# How to cycle through features of a given google.map.data layer

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm building a Google map UI, where a user can select a state which will zoom them into counties which will zoom them into zip codes. This is not homework. It's a legitimate requirement for a client. I have I'm having problems cycling through one of the layers of data that is loaded by GeoJSON data.

What I'm trying to do is get a list of ZIP Codes that is in the Jason file as it's loaded in the GOJ sign because I'm going to use that list of ZIP Codes to look up some data for future styling. In order for me to do that, I need to have that list in a comma-delimited zipcode string list so that I can call an API.

The problem is my `forEach` function call.  In all cases, the `remove(feature)` works, but I am having issues cycling thorugh the features to get properties out.  I am including my JSON code, in hopes that I can find a way to cycle through and get the information I need.  I have attempted this in two ways:

**Attempt #1** (Please look at lines in the bottom half of the counties section)

```
let statetxt;
let countytxt;
let ziptxt;
let ziplist;  //THIS VARIABLE IS IMPORTANT


function processPoints(geometry, callback, thisArg) {
  if (geometry instanceof google.maps.LatLng) {
    callback.call(thisArg, geometry);
  } else if (geometry instanceof google.maps.Data.Point) {
    callback.call(thisArg, geometry.get());
  } else {
    geometry.getArray().forEach(function(g) {
      processPoints(g, callback, thisArg);
    });
  }
}


function initialize(callback) {
  const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    zoom: 4,
    center: { lat: 49.496675, lng: -102.65625 },
  });

  let states = new google.maps.Data({map:map});
  let counties = new google.maps.Data({map:map});
  let zips = new google.maps.Data({map:map});

  states.loadGeoJson('data/states.json');
  states.setStyle({
    zIndex: 1
  })

  states.addListener('click', function (e) {
    statetxt = e.feature.getProperty('NAME');
    document.getElementById("info-box").textContent = statetxt + "; select county.."
    counties.forEach(function(feature) {
      counties.remove(feature);
    });
    zips.forEach(function(feature) {
      zips.remove(feature);
    });
    states.revertStyle();
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    processPoints(e.feature.getGeometry(), bounds.extend, bounds);
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
    states.overrideStyle(e.feature, {strokeWeight: 2, strokeColor: 'green'})
    e.feature.clickable = false;
    let state = e.feature.getProperty('STATE');
    counties.loadGeoJson('data/counties/STATEFP_' + state + '.json');
    counties.setStyle({
      zIndex: 2
    })
  });

  counties.addListener('click', function (e) {
    countytxt = e.feature.getProperty('NAMELSAD');
    document.getElementById("info-box").textContent = statetxt + '; ' + countytxt + '; select zipcode.'
    e.feature.clickable = false;
    GEOID = e.feature.getProperty('STATEFP') + e.feature.getProperty('COUNTYFP');
    console.log (GEOID)
    zips.forEach(function(feature) {
      zips.remove(feature);
    });
    counties.revertStyle();
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    processPoints(e.feature.getGeometry(), bounds.extend, bounds);
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
    counties.overrideStyle(e.feature, {strokeWeight: 2, strokeColor: 'red', zIndex:3})
    ziplist = [];
    zips.loadGeoJson('data/zip_codes/GEOID_' + GEOID + '.json');

    // **********************This does not find the features*********************
    zips.forEach(function(feature) {
        console.log(feature);
    });

    // ***************************report is empty********************************
    console.log(ziplist.toString());

    
    zips.setStyle({
      zIndex:4
    });
  });

  zips.addListener('click', function(e) {
    zips.revertStyle();
    ziptxt = e.feature.getProperty('ZCTA5CE20');
    zips.overrideStyle(e.feature, {strokeWeight: 3, strokeColor: 'blue', zIndex: 5})
    document.getElementById("info-box").textContent = statetxt + '; ' + countytxt + '; ' + ziptxt
  })

}
```

**ATTEMPT #2**. (Note:  this code is replacing the failed portion in Attempt #1)
This attempt creates a function scope error, as while ziplist is created globally at the top of the page, it does not get populated

```
    ziplist = [];
    zips.loadGeoJson('data/zip_codes/GEOID_' + GEOID + '.json', {}, function(features){
      zips.forEach(function(feature) {
        ziplist.push(feature.getProperty('ZCTA5CE20'));
      });
    });
    console.log(ziplist.ToString());
```